# javascript editable table does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to make a html table editable (this code is obtained from an online tutorial link: http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-an-editable-html-table-with-jquery/27425).

```
$("td").dblclick(function () {
        //Obtain and record the value in the cell being edited. This value will be used later
        var OriginalContent = $(this).text();

        //Addition of class cellEditing the cell in which the user has double-clicked
        $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
        //Inserting an input in the cell containing the value that was originally on this.
        $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
        //directing the focus (cursor) to the input that was just created, so that the user does not need to click on it again.
        $(this).children().first().focus();

        //the opening and closing function that handles the keypress event of the input. 
        //A reserved word this refers to the cell that was clicked. 
        //We use the functions first and children to get the first child element of the cell, ie the input.
        $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
            //check if the pressed key is the Enter key
            if (e.which == 13) {
                var newContent = $(this).val();
                $(this).parent().text(newContent);
                $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
            }
        });

    $(this).children().first().blur(function(){
        $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
        $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
    });
    });
```

It seems to work fine. Then I am using the following function to read the contents of the table and create a json representation:

```
function showRefTable(){

  var headers = [];
  var objects = [];
  var headerRow = $('#dataTable thead tr');
  var rows = $('#dataTable tbody tr');

  headerRow.find('th').each(function(){
    headers.push($(this).text());
  });


  for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
    var row = rows.eq(i);
    var object = new Object();
    for (var j=0; j<row.find('td').length; j++){
      object[headers[j]] = row.find('td').eq(j).text();
    }
    objects.push(object);

  }

  var json = JSON.stringify(objects);
  alert(json);

}
```

This function is used as a callback to an onclick event. 
The problem is that the function used to read the table contents shows the original contents even if I make an edit (show page source shows the original content).

Thanks

Comment: Isn't `$(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);' in the `blur` event just reapplying the original text?

Comment: the problem appears to be $(this).parent().text(newContent); $(this).parent().text() returns empty text

Comment: $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent) will restore original content if the user edits and then does not press enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really bad to read table contents from .text(). You will not be able to use any formatting for numbers and many other problems. You'd better of keeping table contents in standalone datasourse object and redrawing table from it every time when user changes values.

I would advise using [kendo grid](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/editing-inline.html) - it's powerfull, reliable js table.

EDIT: your function does not work, becuse you said you call it as callback to onclick event. So you read contents of the table before they actually changed. 
You should read contents when they are saved. In your case, try calling you function when user saves the input (presses Enter)

```
 if (e.which == 13) {
            var newContent = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().text(newContent);
            $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");

          //Now, when content is changed, call your function
          showRefTable();
        }
```

Comment: but this does not answer my question

Comment: see my edit, I hope that helps. But again - don't use such inline editing. At least keep contents in $(element).data - they will be interpreted as they were inputed